# Use typescript only library

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I'm trying to publish and consume typescript only library(w/o `dist` folder with compiled `.js` files)

I created simple library:

src/test/index.ts:

```
export const test = 42;
```

src/index.ts:

```
import {test} from "./test";

export {
  test
};
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "src/index.ts"
}
```

and published it to local npm registry.

Next, I created simple app where I installed this library as dependency.

src/index.ts:

```
import {test} from "test"

console.log(test);
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "src/index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node --experimental-specifier-resolution node --loader ts-node/esm src/index.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "test": "^1.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "sourceMap": true
  }
}
```

When I run it via `npm run start` I got `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_RETURN_PROPERTY_VALUE]: Expected string to be returned for the "format" from the "loader getFormat" function but got type object.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why it happens

The issue is that `ts-node` won't transpile your `node_modules` folder.

## Solution

So you need to explicitly tell `ts-node` to handle your lib.
In your case you have to change your `start` command in the root of the project **from**

```
node --experimental-specifier-resolution node --loader ts-node/esm src/index.ts
```

**to** something like (to transpile ALL `node_modules`. Be careful, it's kinda bad practice)

```
set TS_NODE_IGNORE='' && node --experimental-specifier-resolution node --loader ts-node/esm src/index.ts
```

or a little bit **better** - with [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env)

```
cross-env TS_NODE_IGNORE='' node --experimental-specifier-resolution node --loader ts-node/esm src/index.ts
```